# SEHException thrown while loading an application in a C# Server Process

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-remoting, service-model, servicemodelex

I have a .NET Client which has several C# library files, one of the c# library file loads a third party native library. Now for some reasons we would like to convert the C# library to a new C# server Process which will in turn host the third party native library and use it. 
I have used .NET Remoting framework(HttpServerChannel) to accomplish this. To be able to use the native library APIs I first need to load some of it's internal modules and apps. While loading the apps I get an SEH Exception. 
Note: This works fine with the existing architecture where I have C# library doing this job instead of the C# process.
The call is something like below (the API is used in Teigha Service)
SystemObjects.DynamicLinker.LoadApp("GripPoints", true, true)

Apologies in Advance if I have missed anything as I am new to the .NET REMOTING framework.

Post Updated with code below - 
The C# library that loads the native library has been referenced to create the new server process. The server code is given below. The C# library referenced is "MyClassInternal"

```
`using MyClassInternal;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.Remoting;
 using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
 using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DWGServerHost
{
   class DWGServerHostMain
   {
       public static int serverPort = 9876;
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           HttpServerChannel http = null;
           if (args.Length > 0 && !int.TryParse(args[0], out serverPort))
           {
               serverPort = 9876;
           }

           http = new HttpServerChannel(serverPort);
           ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(http, false);
           RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
           typeof(MyClass),
           "MyClassService",
           WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
           Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
       }
   }
```

}`

On the client side this service is started and then used as below -

```
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine("Path to Exe", "DWGServerHost.exe");
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "9876";
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "Path to Server Location";
                proc.Start();
                //SetErrorMode(0);
                if (proc.HasExited)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not start server");
                    return -1;
                }

                HttpClientChannel http = null;
                http = new HttpClientChannel();
                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(http, false);

                assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Path to DLL");
                Object obj = Activator.GetObject(typeof(MyClass), "http://localhost:9876/MyClassService");
                MyClass myClass = (MyClass)obj;
```

The "MyClassInternal" library, in turn, loads a third party library and creates service. For using the third party library APIs, some initialization has to be made like loading the internal libraries and modules of the third party library. The API used is - 
    `SystemObjects.DynamicLinker.LoadApp("GripPoints", true, true)`

The above API works perfect if we directly load the C# library from our C# library client, and it does not work when the C# Server process that hosts C# library.

**Note**: The class in "MyClassInternal" is already inheriting from MarshalByRefObject. So no issues, in the class.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: Hi Lamar, Updated the post with code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, my updated host process was not placed into the required location after making some changes. 
We can close this question.